# bash exec with different user without extra process

Tags: bash, exec, sudo

Currently I am running the command in my bash script like

```
exec sudo -u mongodb mongod $@
```

The problem is that i would have two processes here. One for `sudo` and one forked from `sudo` `mongod`. Is there a way to avoid `sudo` process?

Comment: How about using su as opposed to sudo?

Comment: I'm wondering why you need the `exec`, and why one extra process is a problem for this.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot achieve specifically that with `sudo`, because of how `sudo` is implemented, from its man page:

> There are two distinct ways sudo can run a command.
>
> If an I/O logging plugin is configured or if the security policy explicitly requests it, a new pseudo-terminal (“pty”) is allocated and fork(2) is used to create a second sudo process, referred to as the monitor...
>
> If no pty is used, sudo calls fork(2), sets up the execution environment as described above, and uses the execve(2) system call to run the command in the child process...

In other words, `sudo` uses two processes.

So if you are trying to avoid `fork()` (or `clone()` these days), you need to look for a different way of changing your user, perhaps [`su`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html); if `euid` is acceptable for your purpose, `suid` bit with corresponding ownership.